# what does the notation $\|x\|$ where x is a vector mean?

Tags: notation

I have come across something that requires minimizing $\|x\|$ where $x$ is a vector? What does the notation $\|x\|$ mean? Is it the two norm or something else?

Comment: If  $||x||$  is used without comment or definition for $x \in \mathbb R^n$, then $||x||$ means the Euclidean norm (the 2-norm). Similarly for $x \in \mathbb C^n$.

Comment: Also, for the record it should be typeset as \|x\| instead of as ||x||.  Compare: $\|x\|$ vs $||x||$.

Comment: It is a norm, but which norm depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

$\lVert . \rVert$ is a norm. There are defininitions for vectors, e.g. $\lVert x \rVert$, or matrices $\lVert A \rVert$.

If nothing extra is said, you can assume the Eucledian norm.

Oterwise subscripts are common, e.g.
$$
\lVert x \rVert_p = \left(\sum_i x_i^p \right)^{1/p}
$$

On the other hand, thanks to norm-equivalence, the specific norm might not matter for some use cases.